# My ajax function with codeigniter is not working

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

### My subscription email is not added to the database and no results for network is shown in console even after using print_r for db query

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    url: base_URL+"Home/subscription_email",
    data: {'email': subscription_email},
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,

    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.sending_subscription_email').html("<h6>SUBMITTING . . .</h6>");
    },

    success: function(data) {
        $('.sending_subscription_email').html("<h6>SUBMITTED</h6>");
        $('#subscription_email').val('');
    },

    error: function(e) {
        $('.sending_subscription_email').html("<h6>Error, please try again</h6>");
    }
});
```

//controller
public function subscription_email() {

```
    $subscriptionData = $this->input->post();

    $subscriptionData['status']         = '1';
    $subscriptionData['notification']   = '0';
    $subscriptionData['date_created']   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    //print_r($subscriptionData); exit();

    //insert data into db
    $insert = $this->Common_model->insertData('subscription', $subscriptionData);
    //print_r($this->db->last_query()); exit();

    if ($insert) {
        echo true;
    } else {
        echo false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the `base_URL+"Home/subscription_email"` code.

Comment: Please show the **essential** code to reproduce your problem. In your case: controller and model where you add email to db.

Your question, as it is written now, needs more details/focus to be answered. Please read 
[**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
and [**How to Ask a Good Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: also: base_URL is a javascript variable you must have defined somewhere. Did you check if it has any value?

Comment: @Vickel yes it is defined

Comment: so how does your url look like?

Comment: @Vickel it is going from index page to subscribtion_email, it calls subscribtion_email using ajax function

Answer (score 0):

Do you have development mode enabled to see errors? It might be possible that production mode is on and some error is being produced that you don't see in Network tab because of that.